# SQL - count rows in join for each day in a time range

Tags: sql

I would like to count for each day valid items in a table. For example:

I have in my table table1 5 entries with following myDate values:

```
 1. 01.10.2022 09:13
 2. 01.10.2022 11:33
 3. 01.10.2022 11:40
 5. 02.10.2022 07:00
 6. 04.10.2022 06:30
```

Now I would like to count for each day the number of rows, with the following result:

```
 1. 01.10.2022 - 3 rows 
 2. 02.10.2022 - 1 row 
 3. 04.10.2022 - 1 row
```

I've already found a statement to iterate through each day of a period and join my table. But the problem is, that I am receiving duplicate values, if there are multiple values valid in my join condition:

```
 1. 01.10.2022 - 1 row 
 2. 01.10.2022 - 1 row 
 3. 01.10.2022 - 1 row 
 4. 02.10.2022 - 1 row 
 5.  ....
```

here is my statement:

```
SELECT    all_date, COALESCE (cnt, 0)
FROM      (SELECT to_date('01/10/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + rownum - 1 AS all_date
           FROM   dual
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30) d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   TRUNC(myDate) as myDate, COUNT(myDate) AS cnt
           FROM     table1 
           GROUP BY myDate) r ON d.all_date < TRUNC(r.myDate);
```

Thanks in advance!

---

edit:
I used d.all_date < trunc(r.myDate) because I would like to select valid values in a timerange.

| myKey | myDatf | myDatt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.10.2022 08:00 | 14.10.2022 08:30 |
| 2 | 01.10.2022 09:00 | 07.10.2022 09:30 |
| 3 | 03.10.2022 11:00 | 03.10.2022 12:00 |
| 4 | 07.10.2022 08:00 | 08.10.2022 11:00 |

Based on previous table, I would like to get the following result. At 04.10.2022 00:00:00 there were 2 valid values with datf < 04.10.2022 00:00:00 and datt > 04.10.2022 00:00:00.

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 02.10.2022 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 03.10.2022 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 04.10.2022 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 05.10.2022 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 06.10.2022 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 07.10.2022 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 08.10.2022 00:00:00 | 2 |
| ... | ... |

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

You should `GROUP BY` expression `TRUNC(myDate)`, not just `myDate`.
Also the join condition should be `d.all_date = r.myDate` since the value in `r` is already truncated and you want one row per day in calendar.

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/45A-NjMi) (I improved naming - all_date feels better name for relation rather than column)

**UPDATE:**
You changed the specification of problem. You need to first join on expression testing range and then group by. Note your example gives wrong result 3 for 07.10. Also note the condition with `between` and `and` behaves differently (and IMO correct) for edge case where time is *exactly* on midnight. Finally note the `count(myKey)` - we cannot use `count(*)` because it would count rows with null right side of left join as 1.

```sql
with table1 (myKey,myDatf,myDatt) as (
  select  1, to_date('01.10.2022 08:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH:MI'), to_date('14.10.2022 08:30','dd.MM.yyyy HH:MI') from dual union all
  select  2, to_date('01.10.2022 09:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH:MI'), to_date('07.10.2022 09:30','dd.MM.yyyy HH:MI') from dual union all
  select  3, to_date('03.10.2022 11:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH:MI'), to_date('03.10.2022 12:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH:MI') from dual union all
  select  4, to_date('07.10.2022 08:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH:MI'), to_date('08.10.2022 11:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH:MI') from dual
)
select all_date.calendar_day, count(table1.myKey)
from      (SELECT to_date('01/10/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + rownum - 1 AS calendar_day
           FROM   dual
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30
) all_date
left join table1 on all_date.calendar_day between table1.myDatf and table1.myDatt
group by all_date.calendar_day
order by all_date.calendar_day;
```

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IxNd5g5j)

Comment: Thanks! That helps! Assumend, my table table1 has instead of myDate field a field DateFrom and a second field DateTo -> is it possible to get all valid values of a day? Thats the reason, why I tried to use all_date < r.myDate

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "valid values" and how does it go with two DateFrom and DateTo columns. If your actual table has different or another columns then you probably simplified question too much. Please provide more realistic example (you can modify my db fiddle) and what output you expect.

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope this is understandable.

Comment: @goldenone Answer updated. Please when communicating on SQL problems, learn to use dbfiddle, don't use markdown tables. People who want to help you are happy solving problems, not preparing test data - it's your work.

Answer (score 1):

The exact query depends on your setup, but basically, you need something like

```
SELECT TRUNC(yourdate) AS yourdate, COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM yourtable 
GROUP BY TRUNC(yourdate) ORDER BY TRUNC(yourdate);
```